# Running tagged RSpec tests within Rubymine

Tags: rspec, rubymine

I am able to run tagged RSpec tests from the command line by tagging the test as follows:

*context "sample test description", :mytag do*

```
     (do some stuff)
```

*end*

I execute the command line as follows and this works fine:
**bundle exec rspec -fd -t mytag**

The problem is that I am trying to run from **within** Rubymine 2017.2.3 and utilize the above tag "mytag".

I've Googled quite a bit but have found no solutions.

The closest I think I have come, is by navigating to Run -> Edit Configurations and trying to specify the tag option in the Runner options field, but haven't gotten it to work.  I've tried several variations.

I also just put --h in Runner options and ran and it does bring up the help.  But --t / --tags does not seem to be recognized the same as it is in the command line.

Can anyone tell me if they have gotten this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out myself.  It appears that you have to use -t, not --tags.  Secondly, I was starting the test by right-clicking on a shared example within my rspec.  What this seems to do is add its own tagging by performing the right click.  However, if I right-click on the file tab at top and then Select 'Run spec 'spec_name' from the menu, then the tagging set in Edit Configurations will work.

The run console will show what tags it ran with.  Example below:

**Run options: include {:focus=>true, :mytag=>true}**

So, in short, add -t {tagname} to Run options field and run the entire RSPEC file.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's because, by default, RubyMine uses a "rails" task, not an rspec task and the parameters are not passed along.
When I created an rspec task, I succeeded in passing the parameters I needed to the runner.

Hope this helps!
[image]